# Documenting Class Methods

Tags: xcode, class, methods, documentation

I don't know if I'm missing something, but how can I get to document my Class Methods?
This doesn't work

```
/*!
  Testing Description.
  @param screenName This a screen name.
  @return void
*/ 
+ (void)startScreenRecording:(NSString *)screenName;
```

It will obviously work with regular instance methods ( - (void)...) but I'm actually looking forward documenting this without installing anything or running any script.

Comment: Hmm. This documentation worked fine for me (Xcode 5.1.1).

Comment: This is really weird but I've realize documentation from classes don't come right away most of the times. You need to spend some time in Xcode, give it a Clean and sometimes even restart Xcode.
Try to declare a class method with documentation above it and if you try to see the documentation it won't show up right away (as it does with instance methods).
I believe this is just something to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it without any other plugins/apps, only clean Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008) and it worked.

Added the documentation in the `@interface`, header file.

#### Code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Testting : NSObject

/*!
 Testing Description.
 @param screenName This a screen name.
 @return void
 */
+ (void)startScreenRecording:(NSString *)screenName;

@end
```

In the implementation file and everywhere I imported and used the header file I could <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> and the popup appeared.

[image: popup]

Comment: Thanks I believe, it's a weird bug.
Try to declare a class method with its documentation included and try to see the same documentation right away in the header file. It'd take some time to show up (depending on the size of your project, maybe? as it re-compiles everything?); however instance classes do appear right away.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, it is a class method (*+ (void)...*) and the documentation is in the *header file* too. It was there instantly. I did not even compile (*Build*) the project once correctly.